# Error in Second Activity "cannot be resolved or not a field"

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I would like to create a simple android app which will have two screens

one is MainActivity
other is SecondActivity

After creation of second activity I am getting an error activity_second cannot be resolved or not a field even though activity_second XML exist don't how to resolve.

setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

Above line showing error

please go through the images to get a clear picture of what the errors i am facing

[SecondActivity.java Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNxWR.jpg)

[Second Activity XML Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0ifi.jpg)

How would i solve the above errors

Thanks in Advance

Comment: post your both the xml file  and the java code in that there will be some issue

Comment: there is also some error in the images name that your using

Comment: i have no problem with MainAcitivity.xml the problem is with SecondActivity.java

Comment: can u mail me u r project then i can help you

Comment: Read the error message at the bottom in the console

Answer (score 3):

Not a big problem..you have given names of your drawable images wrong so your R.java not buliding successfully.

ie android only allows a-z,0-9 in identifiers for drawable images so make names of drawable in lowecase

for example: `IMAGE1.png` is wrong
change to `image1.png` and your R.java will build successfully and your layout will be recognize.
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

Hope this helps.

Comment: i don't have problem with images i have changed to small letters "image1" earlier before i created the SecondActivity

Comment: or you have your String resources not defined in res->value->String.xml  this is what i conclude from your snippet. one more thing there is no xml in your menu folder named `second`. do this changes ,clear your project..

Answer (score 0):

Try to **import com.example1.hello1.R** in SecondActivity.class

Comment: did "import com.example1.hello1.R" in SecondActivity no result same errors persisting any how it has defined in the first line itself while creating SecondActivity "pakage com.example1.hello1.R"